# Problems in adding data to ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, import-contacts, rawcontacts

I am trying to add Contact data in StructuredName with the following code. The problem is GIVEN_NAME is added but other fields are not added.

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                        givenName).build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
                        familyName).build());
```

FAMILY_NAME is not added. If I comment the block code for GIVEN_NAME .. FAMILY_NAME gets added. But rest fields are not getting added.

Comment: Can you give us some more context in the code?

Comment: Problem solved. Answered in the post below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to .build() after adding all the data in the following way:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                    givenName) // Don't call build() here


            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
                    familyName)

            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME,
                    middleName)

            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PREFIX,
                    prefix)

             // and other data that goes into StructuredName


            .build()); // Now call build()
```

Comment: So how do I add fields conditionally? For example, `if (familyName!=null) // add family name`...